# Extending pathlib.Path in Python: Inheritance vs. Composition for Custom Path Operation

Tags: python, pathlib

I'm currently working on a Python project where I need to extend the functionality of the `pathlib.Path` class. My goal is to utilize all the existing methods provided by `pathlib.Path` while adding my own custom methods that follow the model of path.py. These custom methods are aimed at enhancing file path manipulations, such as expanding environment variables and more advanced path operations not directly supported by `pathlib`.

I'm contemplating between two approaches to achieve this: **Inheritance and Composition.**

Here's a brief overview of what I'm considering:

- **Inheritance Approach**: Creating a subclass of `pathlib.Path` and directly adding my custom methods to this subclass. This seems straightforward and allows direct access to the parent class's methods. However, I'm concerned about the implications of extending an immutable class and the correct usage of `__new__` for initialization.
- **Composition Approach:** Creating a new class that contains an instance of `pathlib.Path` as an attribute and delegates method calls to it. Custom methods would be added to this wrapper class. While this approach provides flexibility and keeps the original `Path` class untouched, I'm unsure about the efficiency and elegance of delegating calls for every `pathlib` method.

I'm looking for insights and recommendations from the community on which approach would be more appropriate for extending `pathlib.Path` with custom functionality. Specifically, I'm interested in:

- Which approach is generally considered more pythonic and maintainable?
- Are there any pitfalls or limitations I should be aware of when choosing between inheritance and composition in this context?

If anyone has experience with extending `pathlib.Path`, could you share your thoughts on best practices or examples?

What I tried and works in a notebook:

- Inheritance approach:

  ```
  from pathlib import Path 
  import os

  class PPath(Path):
      _flavour = Path()._flavour

      def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
          # Création d'une instance de MyFile qui est également une instance de pathlib.Path
          self = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
          return self

      def expand(self):
          """
          Expand environment variables and user tilde in the path, then resolve it to an absolute path.
          """
          expanded_path = os.path.expandvars(str(self))
          expanded_path = os.path.expanduser(expanded_path)
          resolved_path = type(self)(expanded_path).resolve()
          return resolved_path

  # Test 
  my_file = PPath('/home/ludivine/Coding/dummy.pkl')
  print(my_file.exists()) 
  print(my_file.is_file())  
  print(my_file.name)  
  print(my_file.expand())
  ```
- Composition approach:

  ```
  from pathlib import Path as BasePath
  import os

  class EmsPath:
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          self._path = BasePath(*args, **kwargs)

      def __getattr__(self, name):
          print(f"Délégation de {name}")
          return getattr(self._path, name)


      def expand(self):
          """
          Expand environment variables and user tilde in the path, then resolve it to an absolute path.
          """
          expanded_path = os.path.expandvars(str(self))
          expanded_path = os.path.expanduser(expanded_path)
          resolved_path = type(self)(expanded_path).resolve()

          return resolved_path

      def __str__(self):
          return str(self._path)

  # Test
  my_file = EmsPath('/home/ludivine/Coding/dummy.pkl')

  print(my_file.exists())  
  print(my_file.is_file())  
  print(my_file.name)  
  print(my_file.expand())
  ```

Comment: My question is: why? A free `def expand(p: Path) -> Path:` sounds fine to me as an API too, and you don't end up in a situation where you'd need to cast `Path`s returned by other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I think neither approach will be very viable in practice (when you'll have libraries that are unaware of `PPath`s or `EmsPath`s) – instead, I'd forget about OOP and go functional with a free helper:

```
# path_helpers.py
import os
import pathlib


def expand(p: pathlib.Path) -> pathlib.Path:
    """
    Expand environment variables and user tilde in the path, then resolve it to an absolute path.
    """
    expanded_path = os.path.expandvars(str(p))
    expanded_path = os.path.expanduser(expanded_path)
    return type(p)(expanded_path).resolve()
```

(Of course, with a function of that signature, you *can* monkey-patch it onto the `pathlib.Path` class, but I'd advise against a sneaky `pathlib.Path.expand = expand`...)

Comment: The reason behind my question stems from my desire to utilize the new version of pytest, which relies on pathlib rather than os.path. However, my entire project calls methods from path.py (a wrapper around os.path). Therefore, I am pondering over the most logical approach to update my code and maintain it over time.

Do you think your approch will be accepted by pytest ?

Comment: It's just a function, Pytest won't care about how you call it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion on adopting a functional approach with helper functions for integrating pathlib into our project. I tried but it seems that functions like isabs defined in path_helper.py won't be directly accessible as methods on pathlib.Path objects.

Comment: Of course they won't, I never said they would be. But it's a fairly straightforward refactoring, and you can even automate it with e.g. [`ast-grep`](https://ast-grep.github.io/).